# How to fix not found element on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to run some query on [here](https://www.scribbr.com/paraphrasing-tool/)

```
from time import sleep
    
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    
driver.get("https://www.scribbr.com/paraphrasing-tool/")
    
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
frames = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='iframe')
for f in frames:
    print("Frame src: ", f.get_attribute('src'))
# Frame src:  https://quillbot.scribbr.com/? 
  # independentTool=true&language=EN&partnerCompany=scribbr.com
# Frame src:  
# Frame src:  https://consentcdn.cookiebot.com/sdk/bc-v4.min.html

driver.switch_to.frame(0)

print(driver.page_source)
# '<html><head></head><body></body></html>' !!!!


input_text_area = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'paraphraser-input-box') # `NoSuchElementException`
```

Answer (score -1):

The desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.scribbr.com/paraphrasing-tool/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#ifrm")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent = arguments[1]", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#paraphraser-input-box"))), "multi-task")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: still have the same error TimeOut Exception! Can you elaborate a full example  in for-loop across a list of text as I mention in my code?

Comment: It can't be _TimeOut Exception_. Did you execute the second line `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`

Comment: The third line trigger the exception `TimeOut Exception`

Answer (score -1):

You have to add some wait time to handle the iframe, because without wait time it's not working all the time, try the below code:

```
heading = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".d-inline-block h1")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", heading)
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ifrm")))
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "paraphraser-input-box").send_keys("multi-task")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MuiButton-root").click()
```

Comment: did you test the code on your side ? It triggers a `NoSuchElementException` on line 6

Comment: I tested the code several times, it is working fine, what is the intention of your question?

Comment: for a list of text =['text1', 'text2', ..], I want to rephrase each one several time (I did only one in the code)  and then save the result in a dict. {'text1': ['phrase1', 'phrase2'], 'text2':[...]}. Your code does not work on my machine. I edit my code above and when I switch to the frame and print the `page_source`, it looks empty

Comment: You changed your question now. First you asked a different question, for that I answered, it is working fine. Now you changed the question and asking that my answer is not working.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer but the question is the same, maybe your solution is running fine on your machine but not on my machine. It is simple! Which version of selenium and driver do you use ?